# Remove item in Checkout

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I am using this code for remove items in Checkout

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'custom_filter_wc_cart_item_remove_link', 10, 3);
function custom_filter_wc_cart_item_remove_link($product_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key)
{
  
    if (is_checkout()) {

        $product_name .= apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', sprintf(
            '<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" class="remove" style="float:left;">&times;</a>',
            esc_url(WC_Cart::get_remove_url($cart_item_key)),
            __('Remove this item', 'woocommerce'),
            esc_attr($cart_item['product_id']),
            esc_attr($cart_item['data']->get_sku())
        ), $cart_item_key);

        return $product_name;
    }
}
```

But it has an error because this line is old code

```
esc_url(WC_Cart::get_remove_url
```

Do you know how fix it

Comment: In the future if you have an error message could you please include it in your question? Thanks!

Comment: But if it was a deprecated function error I'd be surprised if the error didn't tell you which function to use instead.

Answer (score 1):

that function is deprecated, use wc_get_cart_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) instead

```
if (is_checkout()) {
    $product_name .= apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', sprintf(
        '<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" class="remove" style="float:left;">&times;</a>',
        esc_url(wc_get_cart_remove_url($cart_item_key)),
        __('Remove this item', 'woocommerce'),
        esc_attr($cart_item['product_id']),
        esc_attr($cart_item['data']->get_sku())
    ), $cart_item_key);

    return $product_name;
}
```